# frontend layout handle not working

Tags: magento2, layout

frontend layout handle not working other than `default.xml`.

Folder structure:

```
Namespace
  Mymodule
   Block
   view
     frontend
       layout
         default.xml -- loading
         mymodule_index_index.xml -- not loading
   Controller
     Index
       Index.php
   etc
   ....
```

`default.xml` is loading but `mymodule_index_index.xml` not

Comment: layout files are in view part. Your structure seems to be incorrect. Also make sure the layout file name should match your route path.

Comment: @Priyank yeah it finally worked. I thought it matches the module

Comment: it should be `routename_index_index` instead of `mymodule_index_index`